# How do I open all files in a directory in python?

Tags: python

I have the code

```
import os

def Load():
    for filename in os.listdir("directoryPath"):
        content = open(filename, "r")
Load()
```

And I would like to know how to load the files that `filename` returns, at the moment I just get an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Adjectives.txt'`

Comment: You might need to append the directory name to the front of the filename

Comment: looks like youre just passing a string "directoryPath" to `listdir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns only the filename, not the full path. You need to pass the whole path to `open`. You can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine directory and filename:

```
content = open(os.path.join('directoryPath', filename), 'r')
```

Comment: Just one small remark: The name `content` is misleading because it will not contain the content of the file.

Comment: @Matthias: I agree but decided to keep the variable names the same as in the question